# Euclid's algorithm shows wrong conclusion

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

Homework of mine is to create and Euclid's algorithm in java. The task binds me to use both while-loop and if statement. Futhermore - if statement has to be placed inside while-loop.

During this task i faced already infinity-loop problem, somehow manage to get pass it. Now my Euclid's algorithm is giving multiple answers (instead of one) and futhermore they are wrong...

I have searched a couple of topics over here, but none of answers shown in there gave me an answer. I tried to rewrite whole code, and also diffrent conditions for while-loop and if statement.

```
import java.lang.*;

class EuklidesAlgorithm {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
        int a = 25648;
        int b = 15468;

        while (a % b != 0 ){
            int modulo = a % b;
            if (modulo == 0){
                break;
            }else {
                modulo = a % b;
                System.out.println(" Checking for GCD");
                a = b;
                b = modulo;
            }
            System.out.println(" Number " + b + " is GDC of numbers(" + a + "," + b + ").");
        }
    }
}
```

I would like it to give a single answer what is GCD for a and b.

Comment: Please create a [MRE]. Also, please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: just get the last print result out of `while` loop. Also make copies of a,b before the loop as they will change.

Comment: @Doc thank you. Now everything works more than fine :) And thank you Turing for this How to debug small programs. I will read it :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all the condition :

```
modulo==0
```

will alaways be false inside the loop...
and you dont have to change variable prices inside the loop and you also don't have to print answers in every loop so...
the if statement is probably goind to be used to check if any of those two numbers is 0 or if the result is 0 but you can do both